# Частично не подсвечивается синтаксис в scss почему то красным светится '{' хоть никаких ошибок и нет и внутри классов нет никакой подсветки

Tags: html, css, scss, sublime-text

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подсвечиваются красным начальная и конечная фигурные скобки, что очень сильно раздражает и внутри них не работает абсолютно никакая подсветка. Установленные пакет: autofilename, base 16 color schemes, brackethighliter, color highliter, eCSStractor, emmet, goto-css-declaration, package control.

Comment: Вы используете SCSS, а подсветка синтаксиса в Sublime у вас явно выбрана просто CSS

Comment: Дополню комментарий выше: в правом-нижнем углу написано **CSS**, нажмите и найдите там **SCSS** и выберите его

Comment: а почему у меня не работает частично autocompile с scss подсветкой то есть с CSS выпадают все возможные тэги а с scss/sass подсветкой почти никакие